Showing Set of Increasing Sequences of Natural numbers $\{n_1<n_2<\cdots\}$has the same Cardinality as set of fractions of the form $0.a_1a_2\cdots$

Showing the set of increasing(strictly) sequences of natural numbers $\{n_1<n_2<\cdots\}$has the same cardinality as set of real numbers of the form $0.\alpha_1\alpha_2\cdots$

----Zorich Mathematical Analysis 2.4 Exercise 4 a)
So I have absolutely no idea to approach this question, as that in my search across the internet I have not find much relevant information in order to synthesize a proof for this question. So I wish this can be a contributive question to math stackexchange.

In general 0.α1α2⋯
is not a fraction. The passage must have been mistranslated. Can you show that they are both not countable?

@MikhailKatz But showing them being both not countable doesn't necessarily imply they have the same cardinality since Cantor's Theorem.

It's a useful first step :-)  Can you?

I assume you know that the cardinality of the interval $[0,1]$ is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$, and that this cardinality is $2^{\aleph_0}$, where $\aleph_{0}$ is the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$.
Let´s calculate the cardinality of the set of increasing sequences of natural numbers. Suppose $n_1<n_2<\ldots$ is such a sequence. So $n_1$ is any natural number. Now, you have to choose $n_2$ in the set $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{n\in\mathbb{N}:n\leq n_1\}$. Since $\{n\in\mathbb{N}:n\leq n_1\}$ is a finite set, the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{n\in\mathbb{N}:n\leq n_1\}$ is again $\aleph_0$. The same argument is valid to show that you have $\aleph_0$ possibilities for $a_3$, and so on. So, intuitively, there are $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$ increasing sequences of natural numbers. This is the cardinality of $[0,1]$.

Oh and the answer follows, I think you are right.
